# Is Request Scope thread safe in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have created a parent bean that holds all the request scoped beans as shown below

```
@Data
@Component
@RequestScope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
@NoArgsConstructor
public class AuthContext {

    @Autowired
    AuthContextManager authContextManager;

    private AuthRequest authRequest;
    private AuthResponse authResponse;
    private AuthInfo authInfo;

    public AuthContext(AuthRequest authRequest, AuthResponse authResponse, AuthInfo authInfo) {
        this.authRequest = authRequest;
        this.authResponse = authResponse;
        this.authInfo = authInfo;
    }
```

Here the authRequest, authResponse and authInfo are request scoped, As soon as I get a request, i modify the context as shown below and use this authcontext in all the spring components.

```
 @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Object> sale(@RequestBody @Valid AuthRequest authRequest) throws Exception {
        context.setContext(authRequest, new AuthResponse(), new AuthInfo());
```

**Is this completely thread safe ?**

Comment: In theory yes. But without seeing what you are totally doing it will be more or less impossible to answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum, I am using this AuthContext shown above in all the service layers, I am considering this authContext will be unique for each request.  For Eg : If there is a service class that has some business logic I get authContext, validate and update

Comment: Unless you are doing `new AuthContext ` somewhere this will break and thus I said in theory.